# How to provide user authentication option to users in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I am creating a web app that allows users to user their own social network services (Instagram, facebook, spotify, etc.) and display the information like photos, posts, playlists from the SNS.

I know we need each users to authenticate their SNS account first to make the API accessible.

I have no experience with authentication, so I want to get some TIPs of how to do this.

My idea is to provide buttons called `Authenticate` for each SNS. When the user clicks this, I want to open a window for the user to login to their SNS and when the login is successful, it will give a list of whatever information that is related to the SNS (photos, playlists, etc.).

I want to know what I need to know to do this. I know that we need access tokens to access the user's API. Is there a way to use the access token that the user earns by authenticating his account to access the API?

Any advice will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try firebase authentication. A lot of work is involved in what you want to do, and they have done much of this work for us...